# Faster way to add next row's column value to current row within groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add next row's column value to current row within `groupby`.

```
groupby_event_data = event_data.groupby(["user_id", "course_id", "lecture_id"])
pause_event_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['real_time', 'next_real_time'])
n = 0
for each_group, eachdf in groupby_event_data:
    idx = 0
    for index, row in eachdf.iterrows():
        if row['event_from']=='pause_video':
            if idx < len(eachdf)-1:
                pause_event_data.loc[n] = [row.real_time, eachdf.iloc[idx+1]['real_time']] 
            else:
                pause_event_data.loc[n] = [row.real_time, None] 
            n = n+1
        idx = idx + 1
```

For example, with the below sample `event_data`:

```
 event_data:
      user_id  course_id  lecture_id  event_from   real_time
    0    a        c1          l1      pause_video  2018-07-24T19:44:25.869279+00:00
    1    a        c1          l1      pause_video  2018-07-24T19:46:25.869279+00:00    
    2    a        c2          l1      pause_video  2018-07-24T19:47:25.869279+00:00
    3    b        c2          l1      pause_video  2018-07-24T19:45:25.869279+00:00
    4    b        c2          l1      pause_video  2018-07-24T19:50:25.869279+00:00
    5    a        c2          l1      play_video   2018-07-24T19:52:25.869279+00:00
    6    a        c1          l1      pause_video  2018-07-24T19:54:25.869279+00:00
```

I want to get the below `pause_event_data`:

```
 pause_event_data:
       real_time                           next_real_time
    0  2018-07-24T19:44:25.869279+00:00   2018-07-24T19:46:25.869279+00:00
    1  2018-07-24T19:46:25.869279+00:00   2018-07-24T19:54:25.869279+00:00
    2  2018-07-24T19:47:25.869279+00:00   2018-07-24T19:52:25.869279+00:00
    3  2018-07-24T19:45:25.869279+00:00   2018-07-24T19:50:25.869279+00:00
    4  2018-07-24T19:50:25.869279+00:00   None
    5  2018-07-24T19:54:25.869279+00:00   None
```

But as my `event_data` is large, it's taking a long time.

So I was wondering if there's a faster way to run this.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with next processing - first sorting and then filtering only rows with `pause_video`:

```
cols = ["user_id", "course_id", "lecture_id"]
event_data['next_real_time'] = event_data.groupby(cols)['real_time'].shift(-1)
mask = event_data['event_from'].eq('pause_video')
event_data = (event_data.sort_values(cols)
                        .loc[mask, ['real_time','next_real_time']])
print (event_data)
                         real_time             next_real_time
0 2018-07-24 19:44:25.869279+00:00 2018-07-24 19:46:25.869279
1 2018-07-24 19:46:25.869279+00:00 2018-07-24 19:54:25.869279
6 2018-07-24 19:54:25.869279+00:00                        NaT
2 2018-07-24 19:47:25.869279+00:00 2018-07-24 19:52:25.869279
3 2018-07-24 19:45:25.869279+00:00 2018-07-24 19:50:25.869279
4 2018-07-24 19:50:25.869279+00:00                        NaT
```

Original solution:

```
groupby_event_data = event_data.groupby(["user_id", "course_id", "lecture_id"])
pause_event_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['real_time', 'next_real_time'])
n = 0
for each_group, eachdf in groupby_event_data:
    idx = 0
    for index, row in eachdf.iterrows():
        if row['event_from']=='pause_video':
            if idx < len(eachdf)-1:
                pause_event_data.loc[n] = [row.real_time, eachdf.iloc[idx+1]['real_time']] 
            else:
                pause_event_data.loc[n] = [row.real_time, None] 
            n = n+1
        idx = idx + 1
print (pause_event_data)
                   real_time             next_real_time
0 2018-07-24 19:44:25.869279 2018-07-24 19:46:25.869279
1 2018-07-24 19:46:25.869279 2018-07-24 19:54:25.869279
2 2018-07-24 19:54:25.869279                        NaT
3 2018-07-24 19:47:25.869279 2018-07-24 19:52:25.869279
4 2018-07-24 19:45:25.869279 2018-07-24 19:50:25.869279
5 2018-07-24 19:50:25.869279                        NaT
```

Answer (score 2):

To access cells from previous / next row, the standard method
is *shift* (see the documentation). You can use it also in *groupby*.

In your case, instead of your loop, you can run:

```
pause_event_data = event_data[['real_time']].copy()
pause_event_data['next_real_time'] = event_data.groupby(
    ["user_id", "course_id", "lecture_id"]).real_time.shift(-1)
```

Additional remark: Your data should actually be sorted by *real_time*
(in your sample they aren't).